# Laptop don't install the ubuntu from usb port(problem loading UEFI: db X.509)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to do the dual boot on my laptop. I have a Windows 10 version already, and I've been trying to install different versions of Ubuntu, and the problem still persists. I disabled the secure boot option, tried the trust issue with .efi and the same thing continue happening.

My laptop is Acer Aspire 3 A315-54-55WY.

I do not have legacy option, just UEFI.

In the boot menu, I select the USB port where I put ISO and this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why disable secure boot when installing ubuntu. No need to turn off secure boot, ubuntu works great with secure boot on. And is not secure for windows 10 without secure boot.
I also have dual boot win 10 and ubuntu 20.04. and everything works great. My laptop is an acer aspire e15 with an NVME SSD.
But I also had a lot of problems until I installed it successfully. Try to follow these instructions, yes they are in Croatian, but try to translate into your language.
https://www.linuxzasve.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=14176

It would also be advisable to reset the secure boot to factory settings before installing ubuntu if you have already modified something and set the new secure boot as reliable in the bios. Nothing will happen with windows 10, only the secure boot will return to the state it was in before you set it up.